# Developing an OS X Cocoa app to support plugins

Tags: cocoa, plugins, osx-lion

I am developing an OS X app in Cocoa that should support plugins (which are bundles of code, images, etc.) The application works, but with Lion things seem to be more complicated. I used to install a framework in ~/Library/Frameworks/ that the plugin could link against. Now it is more difficult to get permission to write to that directory.

Ideally, the framework that the plugin links to would just live within the main app's bundle. Then an installer wouldn't be necessary. I can't figure out how to do this though. In particular, I don't know where to put the framework during the plugin development. Are there any open source projects that support plugins that I can look to for guidance?

Comment: Why do you need to install a framework? Is it a framework your plugin needs or that your app needs or what?

Comment: The framework contains the API for the plugins, like the object that the root object should subclass or calls that the plugin can make to the hosting application.